# Does a polyethene shrinking signify negative or positive entropy?

Tags: entropy

When I think of something shrinking, I would intuitively think it decreases in entropy as there is less movement. E.g. if a gas was to reduce in volume, there would be less movement of the particles and hence less entropy.

How about for as solid?

I have read if polyethene shrinks, it INCREASES in entropy.

Why is this the case?

Comment: As polyethene shrinks, it doesn't necessarily reduce in volume, to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, could you please elaborate? Doesn't shrink imply a decrease in volume?

Comment: It shrinks in one direction and expands in the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When stretched, the polymer chains elongate and are held taut. This means there are more crosslinks and fewer opportunities for internal degrees of freedom (movement). A relaxed polymer is not held taut and therefore can freely move, having more degrees of freedom, and an associated increase in entropy.